# Javascript Slider Client Side Update

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a slider in my html homepage. slider cycles through list items.A list item has an image, a header and and a text tag. I want do develop an admin page so that i can view current items in the slider, delete /update slider contents and create a new sliding item. Is it possible to achieve this goal without using server side scripting ? If this is not possible with client side scripting what is the best practice to do this using server side scripting ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to configure for every viewer then server side.

However if you only want to configure the current client JavaScript may offer you some configuration choices, for example choosing from a predefined list of items to cycle

Comment: the files are different though. i.e. slides are in index.html and i want to have an admin.html page. Is it possible to update the unordered list items in index.html page from admin.html  ? Thanks